# Missing dependencies after using docker-compose with nodeJS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am stating my docker-compose with some microservices and having issues with the same package with all three microservices.

docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  microservice:
    driver: bridge
  api-gateway:
    external: true

services:
  api-gateway:
    container_name: api-gateway
    build:
      context: ./gateway-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    depends_on:
      - users
      - db
      - emailer
      - baldar
    restart: on-failure
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - ./gateway-api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - microservice
  users:
    container_name: users
    build:
      context: ./users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - ./users:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8877:8877
    networks:
      - microservice
  emailer:
    container_name: emailer
    build:
      context: ./emailer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    restart: on-failure
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - ./emailer:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8878:8878
    networks:
      - microservice
  baldar:
    container_name: baldar
    build:
      context: ./baldar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    restart: on-failure
    command: npm run start:dev
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./baldar:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8879:8879
    networks:
      - microservice
  db:
    container_name: MySQL
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=gmail100
    volumes:
      - D:\Projects\Warehouse\Backend\db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - microservice
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node
```

The issue :

```
> NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch


c[6:48:15 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...


src/baldar/baldar.module.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/config' or its corresponding type declarations.


4 import {ConfigModule} from "@nestjs/config";

                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


[6:48:17 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

What seems to be the problem?
What do I try?

1. Delete container and recreate
2. Re-install the dependency
3. I install other packages, and they work fine without a problem

What can I do..

Comment: take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/micalevisk/9ee47135b22f284dd73de6ea6d5aa864) Dockerfile I've made for nestjs apps

Comment: I don’t see different…

Comment: The first thing I'd try is deleting all of the services' `volumes:` blocks, which replace the code and `node_modules` trees from the Docker images with different content.  (The anonymous volume for `node_modules` will cause Docker to ignore changes to the `package.json` file, which you probably don't want.)

Comment: But how it get to know changes in package json and node models if there no volume?